# Asynchronous HTTP requests with co_await

Tags: c++, c++20

I have multiple `std::function`s that are called on the main thread (not on different threads) in my app (as the result of an asynchronous HTTP requests), for example:

```
namespace model { struct Order{}; struct Trade{};}

std::function<void (std::string)> func1 = [](std::string http_answer)
{
    std::vector<model::Order> orders = ParseOrders(http_answer);
    std::cout << "Fetched " << orders.size() << " open/closed orders.");
}

std::function<void (std::string)> func2 = [](std::string http_answer)
{
    std::vector<model::Trade> trades = ParseTrades(http_answer);
    std::cout << "Fetched " << trades.size() << " trades.");
}
```

How to call `process_result` when the both `func1` and `func2` have parsed HTTP answers?

```
auto process_result = [](std::vector<model::Order> orders, std::vector<model::Trades> trades)
{
    std::cout << "Matching orders and trades.";
};
```

Is there some solution with `co_await` or something like this?

Comment: The return type of `func1` and `func2` don't match the arguments of `process_results`. You are missing the code that shows how those get their parameters.

Comment: @Caleth I corrected the code, `func1` and `func2` are called when HTTP requests complete and parse the text responses. When both orders and trades are parsed I need `process_result` to be called.

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of synchronization point. Have not used co_await so far so this might not be what you are looking for, however in c++17 I'd go for a `std::promise` / `std::future`, maybe like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <future>

std::promise<std::string> p1;
std::function<void (std::string)> func1 = [](std::string http_answer)
{
    // std::vector<model::Order> orders = ParseOrders(http_answer);
    // std::cout << "Fetched " << orders.size() << " open/closed orders.");
    p1.set_value(http_answer);
};

std::promise<std::string> p2;
std::function<void (std::string)> func2 = [](std::string http_answer)
{
    // std::vector<model::Trade> trades = ParseTrades(http_answer);
    // std::cout << "Fetched " << trades.size() << " trades.");
    p2.set_value(http_answer);
};

int main () {

    // whenever that happens...
    func1("foo");
    func2("bar");

    // synchronize on func1 and func2 finished
    auto answer1 = p1.get_future().get();
    auto answer2 = p2.get_future().get();

    auto process_result = [&](/* std::vector<model::Order> orders,  std::vector<model::Trades> trades */)
    {
        std::cout << "Matching orders and trades... " << answer1 << answer2;
    };

    process_result();

    return 0;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c74f00125999fb6

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future

Comment: Does `p1.get_future().get();` block the thread? In my app it should not.

Comment: Yep it will block the calling thread. However, ```std::future``` has ```wait```and  ```wait_for``` where you can poll for the result status (similar to poll / select).

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for

Comment: I think `p1.get_future().get();` is assumed to be called on a separate thread. What will change in your code if I simply remove `get_future()` calls? And use simple variables instead of `promise`?

Comment: That's the common use case, yes. If your application is guaranteed to be single threaded you can just store your result in a simple variable along with a certain condition to check that the result is ready. In my code above you could of course just check for the result string to be ```!empty()```

However, since you asked for something like ```co_await```, I thought there is surely some multithreading threading in place.

Comment: I did not find a better solution that using some aggregator that calls a function when its arguments have been set, see https://github.com/dmitriano/Awl/blob/master/Tests/AggregatorTest.cpp